# Javascript generate AES using cap and small cap letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, cryptojs

I'm setting up the code to generate the AES hash using with 3 random numbers to generate the hash, but I don't want to generate the hash that come with the keys such as like `?`, `/`, `+`, `=`...etc.

Here is the output for the hash that I use to generate it:

```
U2FsdGVkX1+nF+bhzvA/sFnQKgOKwrRNJbqr+XzJ/2k=
```

I want to generate the AES hash that start with `FM` cap letters with the long random cap and small cap letters to make it to show like this:

```
FMfcgxwCgCRTpGWxctmfLpRBZxVcrkdM
```

Here is what I use to encrypt and decrypt the hash:

```
//encrypt the hash
var hash = '234';
var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(hash, "My Secret Passphrase");


//decrypt the hash
var decryptbytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(hash.toString(), "My Secret Passphrase");
var email_number = decryptbytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

What I'm expecting to do is to encrypt the hash using with the long random cap and small cap letters like `FMfcgxwCgCRTpGWxctmfLpRBZxVcrkdM` without the keys `?`, `-`, `=` or whatever it is and I want to decrypt the hash to go back to numbers that I enter when I encrypted it.

Can you please show me an example how I could use `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` to encrypt the numbers to turn into 32 letters that start with `FM` with the cap and small cap letters?

Thank you

Comment: AES 256bit hashes are 44 character long. Also, you cannot limit it to use only certain characters.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I didn't know that AES 256 bit hashes are 44 character long. So what do I need to use then?

Comment: I don't know any algorithm that matches your specific request, can I  ask you why do you need that formatting?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I want to use it to encrypt the number for email use. So is it possible to use `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` to encrypt the numbers to turn into letters?